# PySpark: how to check if a column only contains the `F.lit(True)`?

Tags: pyspark

I was hoping to find the `.all()` function but it doesn't seem to work. E.g. if my dataframe is

```
+----+
| tmp|
+----+
|true|
|true|
|true|
|true|
+----+
```

how do I return `true` to signify that all rows are `true`?

Answer (score -1):

**Try Below code**

```
df.filter(col('tmp') != true).count() == 0
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use the `min` function

For example
`df.select(F.min("tmp"))`

Comment: this will skip `NULL`s

Comment: it's ok. I know for sure it's all true or false.